# how to predict new cases using the neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network

Using RGUI. I have a dataset called Data. The response variable that I'm interested in is contained in the first column of `Data`.

I have training sets of `Data` called `DataTrain` and `DataTest`.

With `DataTrain` I trained a neural network model (called `DataNN`) using the package and function `neuralnet`.

```
> DataNN = neuralnet(DataTrain[,1] ~ DataTrain[,2] + DataTrain[,3], hidden = 1,
    data = DataTrain)
```

Does anyone know how to create a prediction on this model using the test set (`DataTest`)?

Normally (for other models) I would use `predict()` for this. E.g.

```
> DataPred = predict(DataNN, DataTest)
```

But when doing this for `neuralnet` I get:

```
> DataPred = predict(DataNN, DataTest)

Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "nn"
```

Obviously I can't run `predict()` on this model. Does anyone know of any alternatives?

I've checked the help for `neuralnet` and I found a method called `prediction` in the page 12 of the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf). I don't think it's what I want at all though, or at least I don't know how to apply it to my `Data`.

Any help would be appreciated (if there is any solution to this at all).

Answer (score 22):

The **compute** method does what you are after, I copied this example from the help file and added some comments:

```
 # Make Some Training Data
 Var1 <- runif(50, 0, 100) 
 # create a vector of 50 random values, min 0, max 100, uniformly distributed
 sqrt.data <- data.frame(Var1, Sqrt=sqrt(Var1)) 
 # create a dataframe with two columns, with Var1 as the first column
 # and square root of Var1 as the second column

 # Train the neural net
 print(net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Sqrt~Var1,  sqrt.data, hidden=10, threshold=0.01))
 # train a neural net, try and predict the Sqrt values based on Var1 values
 # 10 hidden nodes

 # Compute or predict for test data, (1:10)^2
 compute(net.sqrt, as.data.frame((1:10)^2))$net.result
 # What the above is doing is using the neural net trained (net.sqrt), 
 # if we have a vector of 1^2, 2^2, 3^2 ... 10 ^2 (i.e. 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 ... 100), 
 # what would net.sqrt produce?

 Output:
 $net.result
             [,1]
 [1,] 1.110635110
 [2,] 1.979895765
 [3,] 3.013604598
 [4,] 3.987401275
 [5,] 5.004621316
 [6,] 5.999245742
 [7,] 6.989198741
 [8,] 8.007833571
 [9,] 9.016971015
[10,] 9.944642147
# The first row corresponds to the square root of 1, second row is square root
# of 2 and so on. . . So from that you can see that net.sqrt is actually 
# pretty close
# Note: Your results may vary since the values of Var1 is generated randomly.
```

Comment: I ran into this error when I used compute: no applicable method for 'compute' applied to an object of class "nn." It's a conflict with the compute method in dplyr. I fixed by calling like this: neuralnet::compute().

Comment: Sorry, in neuronal network how I could select better predictors?

Comment: this code fails with `Error in if (ncol(newdata) == length(object$model.list$variables)) { : 
  argument is of length zero`

Comment: @baxx: `as.data.frame(...)` is needed around the `1:10...`

Answer (score 2):

The function for prediction is `prediction`, not `predict`.

So try `DataPred = prediction(DataNN, DataTest)` instead of `DataPred = predict(DataNN, DataTest)`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is compute(nn, test)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the neuralnet's version of predict i.e.

```
DataPred <- compute(DataNN, DataTest)
```

If you're using dplyr to do any manipulation then you'll need to specifically declare the library then the function name like so

```
DataPred <- neuralnet::compute(DataNN, DataTest)
```

BTW never use the equals sign when assigning values to variables, unfortunately that's bad practice.

Comment: could you explain why the equals sign is bad practice please

Comment: The convention I used is in line with Google's R Style guide. But the main reason is that the <- convention actually evaluates the code on the right and assigns the results of the code on right to the variable on the left (in this case, results from compute(DataNN, DataTest) are assigned to variable DataPred). The equals sign is usually used within functions. In reality there's no major differences between "=" and "<-" but conceptually in R they're slightly different.